# Puppeteer Use Multiple Proxies and Change Automatic Proxy if Proxy Refused Connection

Tags: node.js, proxy, puppeteer

Can you tell me if this is possible?

I want to use multiple proxies and automatically change the proxy if the proxy refused connection.

```
args: [
    '--proxy-server=127.0.0.1:9876', // Or whatever the address is
]
```

So with this, you can use one single proxy, but how is it possible to use multiple and let it automatically change if it refuses connection?

Answer (score 12):

#### Use Tor.

You can [install the `tor` package](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87170) which will allow you to browse with Puppeteer through the Tor network, and change your identity (IP address) very easily.

Launch Puppeteer with Tor using the `--proxy-server` flag:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: [
    '--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9050',
  ],
});
```

Then, on [`page.on('response')`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-response), change the proxy using [`child_process.exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) if the response was not successful ( [`response.ok() === false`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#responseok) ).

The following command will create a new Tor identity:

```
(echo authenticate \'""\'; echo signal newnym; echo quit) | nc localhost 9051
```

**Example Usage:**

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
      '--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'
    ],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  let current_ip_address = '';
  
  page.on('response', response => {
    if (response.ok() === false) {
      exec('(echo authenticate \'""\'; echo signal newnym; echo quit) | nc localhost 9051', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (stdout.match(/250/g).length === 3) {
          console.log('Success: The IP Address has been changed.');
        } else {
          console.log('Error: A problem occured while attempting to change the IP Address.');
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Success: The Page Response was successful (no need to change the IP Address).');
    }
  });
  
  await page.goto('http://checkip.amazonaws.com/');
  
  current_ip_address = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.textContent.trim());
  
  console.log(current_ip_address);
  
  await browser.close();
})();
```

> **Note:** Tor may take a moment to change identities, so it might be a good call to verify that the IP Address is different before continuing with your program.

Comment: thank you sir for this code snippet. Do you have any idea if it will work with headless chrome instance? I would like to use puppeteer with tor on my virtual server running node.js. Are there any quirks with that setup?

Comment: What you have here is awesome. I went to implement it and it worked great. It should be noted, though, that `page.on('response'` checks every request, including those for css, images, js. So if you go to any modern webpage you could easily have 10-20 requests that you are checking for and a lot of them don't have a status of `ok()` so you end up switching more often than you normally want.

Comment: I want to add that if you are using Mac OSX first you need to create a hashed password for Tor and update the /usr/local/etc/tor/torrc file as stated here (https://cuyu.github.io/other/2016/05/26/Install-and-setup-Tor) for it to work